# aria-live="polite" doesn't announce selected form controls like radio button/checkbox

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

Facing a strange problem with `aria-live="polite"`, if the loaded content has form controls, like radio buttons or checkbox.

NVDA just reads the text of radio buttons, but doesn't announce anything about which one is selected or checked.

```
<a aria-label="Click Me" href="#">Click Me</a>
<div id="myForm" aria-live="polite"></div>
```

Here is the **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gP1FPRXgZGusDic3Vv56?p=preview)**.

Comment: You are not supposed to put things like form controls inside an ARIA live region.

Comment: Actually we are using AngularJS with ui-rotuer which updates a view/ portion of a page when a route/URL is matched, hence the implementation.

Comment: You are still using it the wrong way, AngularJS or no AngularJS

Comment: Your code sample doesn't load. Try including it here? Without seeing the radios no-one can help you.

Comment: Does it read all of the radio button options, or just the selected one?

Comment: @stringy: please click on the link "Click Here" radio buttons will load. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen : It reads all the radio button options, but doesn't state which one is selected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you haven't gotten a good answer yet. Welcome to the world of accessibility.

Your issue isn't with `aria-live=“polite”` -- it's just the way that NVDA works. So I guess the good news is you did it right. For the following example I changed the default option to "Two Day" so I could confirm what was being read wasn't just the first option.

With your code, I hear:

> Click me link

I then press SPACE to activate the link, and I hear:

> Choose a shipping method:
>
> Overnight
>
> Two day <-- You want this to say "selected/checked/etc"
>
> Ground

If I tab into the group, I hear:

> Choose a shipping method:
>
> radio button not checked Two day

To get your desired behavior I updated your HTML to generate an invisible `<span>` that contains the text  `Default is "Two day"`. Now what I hear is:

> Click me link

I then press SPACE to activate the link, and I hear:

> Choose a shipping method default is Two Day:
>
> Overnight
>
> Two day
>
> Ground

This is what it looks like (Note the span inside the legend):

```
<fieldset role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="shipMethod" id="myFieldSet">
    <legend id="shipMethod">Choose a shipping method<span style="display:none;"> Default is "Two day"</span>:</legend>
    <input name="shipping" id="overnight" type="radio" value="overnight">
    <label for="overnight">Overnight</label>
    <br>
    <input name="shipping" id="twoday" type="radio" value="twoday" checked="checked">
    <label for="twoday">Two day</label>
    <br>
    <input name="shipping" id="ground" type="radio" value="ground">
    <label for="ground">Ground</label>
</fieldset>
```

You can also get a similar affect by messing around with changing the control focus, but that's a bit un-cool to the user with a screen reader.

This isn't hard to implement and in a way is a kind of elegant in that the users that need the extra help get it without changing it for other users.

Comment: Yes, I did the same work around, however it works fine for the first time. But after that it would announce two times like "Default is 'Two day'" and then Two day radio button checked. Which is kind of annoying. :(

Comment: Don't think of it as being annoying, think of it as being clear and well described. :-)